# Only first index of tuples list being used

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, tuples

im currently returning a list of Tuples using the Zip function:

The returned data is: `[(13, 3), (12, 3), (11, 3), (10, 3), (9, 3), (8, 3), (6, 3), (5, 3), (4, 3)]`

im looping through the data to use it but currently only the first index is being printed.

```
CheckPath = self.CheckQueenPathDown(QueenRowColumn,TheComparisonQueen) #This is where the list of tuples is being used
print(CheckPath) # this shows all the correct data when i print it.
for TheQueenMoves in QueenMoves:
    for a,b in list(self.pieces.items()):
        for CheckThePath in CheckPath:
             if TheComparisonQueen == TheQueenMoves and TheComparisonQueen[0] >= 0 and TheComparisonQueen[1] <= 7 and \
                TheComparisonQueen[1] >= 0 and TheComparisonQueen[0] <= 7 and CheckThePath != b: # this is the line im trying to use it in.
                self.placepiece(piece, row = MoveRow, column = MoveColumn)
                print(CheckThePath)
```

This is the code i am getting the info from:

```
 Example data: 
 QueenRowColumn: (3,3)
 TheComparisonQueen: (7,3)

 def CheckQueenPathDown(self, QueenRowColumn, TheComparisonQueen):


row = []
column = []

CurrentLocation = QueenRowColumn
#MoveLocation = TheComparisonQueen
a = QueenRowColumn[0]
b = QueenRowColumn[1]

for i in range (-10,0):

    row.append(CurrentLocation[1] - i)
    column.append(a)

Down = zip(row,column)

#Down.remove(TheComparisonQueen)

return Down
```

im currently trying to use all the varibles of the returned data by looping through it, however only the first index appears when i print it, i dont understand what the problem is. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I guess you need to specify the index of ``CheckThePath ``, like ``CheckThePath[0]`` or ``CheckThePath[1]``

Comment: Sure but is there a reason the loop isn't looping through all the data?

Comment: Can you simply print out the item in loop after first line?, ``for c in Checkpath: print c[0],c[1]``

Comment: I can print out the first two indexes which would be `13` and `3` of the tuple `(13,3)`  but when i try to print out anymore, i get `Tuple index out of range` error. meaning the other variables are not being looped through.

Comment: ``a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
for item in zip(a,b):
    print(item[0],item[1])`` I cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: i will update the question will the all the code that is being used for this loop.

Comment: @R.yan btw, the first two indexes are printing but they are printing the two numbers within one Tuple `(13,3)` which is the very first tuple in the list of tuples. If i try to do `CheckThePath[3]` i get `Tuple index out of range`.

Comment: `zip` doesn't return a list on Python 3.

Comment: @user2357112 Oh ok, even if it doesnt return a list the data should still be able to be looped through right? btw i also tried `tt = list(CheckPath)` and looped through `tt` and that still did not work.

Comment: @hiihihihelloo Yes you can still loop it, but user2357112 is right. You can't reuse it. Since in your code you put it in a nested loop. so the second time loop to it, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`zip` doesn't make a list on Python 3. If you need a list, call `list` on the result.

On Python 3, `zip` returns an iterator, which is exhausted after iterating over it once. If you try to reuse it, you get no elements out of it.

Comment: i called a list on the returned data, i still got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
def CheckQueenPathDown(self, QueenRowColumn, TheComparisonQueen):


    row = []
    column = []

    CurrentLocation = QueenRowColumn
    #MoveLocation = TheComparisonQueen
    a = QueenRowColumn[0]
    b = QueenRowColumn[1]

    for i in range (-10,0):

        row.append(CurrentLocation[1] - i)
        column.append(a)

    Down = zip(row,column)

    #Down.remove(TheComparisonQueen)

    return list(Down)
```

Since `return list(ZIP_OBJ)` will allocate memory to it so you can reuse it in the nested loop.

Comment: Btw, i did not post all my code and i just found out that after the first if the data seems to disappear,  i printed the data after the first If and it was there, by the thrid if only the first tuple was left. Do if's matter?

Comment: Never mind, even after the first `if` the information is gone, i have no idea whats going on.